# Run Time error 1004: Select Method of Worksheet class failed with (varCellContent.Parent.Name)

Tags: vba, excel

The code edits, then copies data from a temporary sheet to the current workbook.  I am using varCellContent to ask the user to choose the source sheet.  I had no trouble when testing the code as I was building it by using F8 to step through (and the code still works perfectly like this).

But when I run the macro normally, I am getting

> Run Time error 1004: Select Method of Worksheet class failed

on the following line:

```
Workbooks(varCellContent.Parent.Name).Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
```

The following may not be relevant to the cause of the problem but I have read a bit about it while searching for an answer.
It sounds like using .Select is not a good idea, but there are 2 reasons I thought it was useful in this situation.

1. I don't have to name the sheet for each of the following rows of code that delete and move the columns.
2. When building and debugging the code I wanted the sheet to be visible so that I could see what was happening as I stepped through each line of code.

So taking those 2 reasons into account is there still a better way to avoid using .Select?

```
Sub ImportNewData()
'
'
' Import data, save as new workbook

Dim LR As Long
    LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Clear data
    Range("A3:I" & LR).ClearContents

   ' User choose source sheet
    Dim varCellContent As Worksheet
    Set varCellContent = Application.InputBox _
        (prompt:=" " & vbNewLine & "Click any cell in the Aged AP Summary that has been exported from Systematic to Excel, then click OK", Type:=8).Parent

    Workbooks(varCellContent.Parent.Name).Worksheets("Sheet1").Select

   'Delete unrequired columns
    Columns("E:I").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Columns("E:I").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

Comment: That worked thanks! :-)  I am still puzzled as to why .Select worked when using F8 to step through but not normally

Comment: When debugging the application makes modifications to the state of your machine, so it runs differently than it debugs.